# What is the easiest most complete solution for deploying django apps?

Tags: python, django

I want to deploy a `django` app to a remote server. In rails they have `capistrano` that handles installing dependencies, gem updating, git updating, shell commands, etc.

Is there anything built for `django` that is as complete and as easy to use as `capistrano`?

Note: I think you can also use `capistrano` with `django`, but is there anything specifically built in `python` for `django`?

Close?: The solution many people have brought up was given to a 2010 question. Unless you guys have absolute confidence in the solution, please don't close this question. Software constantly changes and there's always innovation. Are there any new/addition solutions since 2010?

Comment: @gawel yea, I've heard about fabric. Wondering if anything else popped up since 2010 when that question was asked.

Comment: ansible & salt but fabric still the easiest to use

Comment: +1 for Fabric. A close second would be deploying to Heroku or OpenShift, pretty hard to beat "git push heroku master" to deploy code, for example, but I guess it depends on where you're deploying.

Comment: please offer a bounty on the "old" question and ask for up-to-date answers... it's better to have up-to-date answers than duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fabric](https://github.com/fabric/fabric) to deploy a django app to a remote server. Fabric is a Python library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks. You can use Fabric same as capistrano gem. take a look of this live code.

```
from fabric.api import *


def dev():
    env.user = "example"
    env.hosts = ["example.com", ]
    env.dev = True
    env.prod = False


def prod():
    env.user = "example"
    env.hosts = ["192.68.1.23", ]
    env.dev = False
    env.prod = True


def start_virtualenv():
    local("workon django_test")

# Local developent
def start_dev_server():
    local("python manage.py runserver_plus --settings django_test.settings.dev")

def start_dev_server_z():
    local("python manage.py runserver_plus --settings django_test.settings.dev 0.0.0.0:9000")

def start_dev_shell():
    local("python manage.py shell --settings django_test.settings.dev")

def start_dev_dbshell():
    local("python manage.py dbshell --settings django_test.settings.dev")

def run_dev_command(command_name=""):
    """Run a command with the settings thing already setup"""
    local("python manage.py %s --settings django_test.settings.dev" % command_name)

# Remote serving
def run_prod_command(command_name=""):
    """ Just run this command on remote server """
    with cd("/srv/www/django_test/app/"):
        with prefix("source /home/user/.virtualenvs/agn/bin/activate"):
            run("python manage.py %s --settings django_test.settings.prod" % command_name)

def restart_prod_server():
    """ Start a gunicorn instance using the supervisor daemon from the server """
    run("sudo supervisorctl restart django_test")

# Deploy and shit
def deploy(commit="true"):
    """
    TODO: there is sure a better way to set that prefix thing
    """
    if commit == "true":
        local("git add .")
        local("git commit -a")
        local("git push")

    with cd("/srv/www/agn/app"):
        run("git pull")

    if env.dev:
        account_name = 'exampledev'
    else:
        account_name = 'user'
    prefix_string = 'source /home/%s/.virtualenvs/django_test/bin/activate' % account_name

    with cd("/srv/www/django_test/app/requirements"):
        with prefix(prefix_string):
            run("pip install -r prod.txt")

    with cd("/srv/www/django_test/app"):
        with prefix(prefix_string):
            run("python manage.py migrate --settings django_test.settings.prod")
            run("python manage.py collectstatic --settings django_test.settings.prod --noinput")

    restart_prod_server()
```